# How to retrieve a single attribute value in a collection based on the document id?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

How do I retrieve a document single attribute value, by using the document userId?

First I return the document `_Id` using the following code

```
Session.set('getUserId', Al.findOne({_id: Session.get('appealId')}));
console.log(Session.get('getUserId').userID);
```

I can see the `userID` is printed successfully in the console, now I want to use the `userID` to retrieve another value from `Meteor.users` collection.

Here is my code:

```
Session.set('userDetails', Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Session.get('getUserId').userID}));
console.log(Session.get('userDetails').profile.annualLeave);
```

but it doesn't seem to work, I get the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined
```

I tried to change `Session.get('userDetails').profile.annualLeave` to `Session.get('userDetails').username` and I still get the same error telling me that `username` is undefined

**UPDATE :**

for the `appealId` session, I use it to store the `_Id` of the item from the router. to use it later to retrieve the `userID` (Attribute inside the item).

Here is the code:

```
Router.route('/appeal/:_id', function(){
  Session.set("appealId", this.params._id);
  this.render("navbar", {to:"navbar"});
  this.render("appealDetails", {to:"main"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that

```
Session.get('userDetails')
```

is not defined, which in turn means that the call to

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Session.get('getUserId').userID})
```

Must have not returned anything

You are not clear how these two pieces of code are related, and your repeated use of Session seems convoluted. I don't even know why this line of code is there

```
console.log(Session.get('test').userID);
```

Unless 'test' is something you stored earlier

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, I fixed it, I meant "getUserId" session. Sorry again

Comment: ok, but you are still not near the root casue. Where does Session.get('appealId') come from?

Comment: I store its value using the routers. I updated my question :)